# Setting C for Linear SVM

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

Here's my question:

I have a medium size data set about the condition of a hydraulic system.

The data set is represented by 68 variables plus condition of the system(green, yellow, red)

I have to use several classifiers to predict the behaviour of the system so I have divided my data set into training and test set as follows:

(Talking about the conditions, the colour means: red-Warning, yellow-Pay attention, green-Good)

That's what I wrote

```
Tab$Condition=factor(Tab$Condition, labels=c("Yellow","Green","Red")) 

set.seed(32343)

reg_Control = trainControl("repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats=5, verboseIter = T, classProbs =T)

inTrain = createDataPartition(y=Tab$Condition,p=0.75, list=FALSE)

training = Tab[inTrain,]

testing = Tab[-inTrain,]
```

I'm using a SVM linear classifier to predict the behaviour of the system.

I started by using a random value for C to see what kind of results I should get.

```
svmLinear = train(Condition ~.,data=training, method="svmLinear", trControl=reg_Control,tuneGrid=data.frame(C=seq(0.1,1,0.1))) 

svmLPredictions = predict(svmLinear,newdata=training)


confusionMatrix(svmLPredictions,training$Condition) 



#misclassification of 129/1655 accuracy of 92.21%


svmLPred = predict(svmLinear,newdata=testing) 


confusionMatrix(svmLPred,testing$Condition)


#misclassification of 41/550 accuracy of 92.55%
```

I've used a SVM linear classifier to predict the behaviour of the system.

As Isaid before I started with RANDOM VALUE FOR C.

How do I decide then about the best value to use for the analysis??

Sorry if the question is banal but I'm a beginner!

Answers will be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: which package are you using? If you look at the implementation documentation it will give you a default value  used. I think the default cost value in most implementations is 1. you can keep all other  parameters fixed  use values of C smaller and  greater than 1 and see which direction improves the result . Basically this is the essence of a gridSearch

Comment: I'm using caret! So you suggest to try with value grater and smaller than 1 for C..and see what kind of differences/improvements I get in terms of accuracy and misclassification...?? Another important question is...Should I check the results for C from "view()" and "confusionMatrix()" everytime?? Thanks

Comment: Actually the trained model will tell you  accuracy scores for various parameters.  Just type `svmLinear` on console . For the first part, use `tunegrid=data.frame(C=c(0.5, 1,1.5))` .

Comment: I'm keeping tuneGrid=data.frame(C=seq(0.1,1,0.1) as the suggested one implies some errors in the computation(I've just tried!). If I type svmLinear on console I can see the results, and the best one is C = 0.2 and Accuracy = 0.91. Should I check the results also for training and testing with confusion matrix or is the svmLinear typing on console exhaustive...? Once I've done this I could try with tuneGrid=data.frame(C=seq(1,10,1) What do you think?

Comment: No, you don't have to analyse it with confusion matrix. All that was already done by the k-fold cross validation process governed by the `tuneControl`parameters. Actually we don;t need the  `testing` part at all unless we want to  create many other models (like `svmRadialWeights` ) and compare the performances of these models with each other.

Comment: I have to use other classifiers for my analysis.. so I need to see the results of confusionMatrix to check the one that best perform in testing!

Comment: Yes. BTW you can also directly compare performance metrics generated by caret for each model . See here https://machinelearningmastery.com/compare-models-and-select-the-best-using-the-caret-r-package/ .  Use `resamps$values`  for a clean dataframe of results ,and make boxplot just as done there.  This also helps compare variances within each model's performance.  There is some subjectivity involved in final selection of model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caret calls other packages  to  run the actual modelling process. Caret itself is only a (very powerful) convenience package in this regard. However ,it does that automatically so a user might not realize this easily unless an error is thrown 
Anyway , I have cobbled together an example to explain the process.

```
library(caret)
data("iris")

set.seed(1024)

tr <- createDataPartition(iris$Species,  list = FALSE)
training <- iris[ tr,]
testing  <- iris[-tr,]

#head(training)
fitControl <- trainControl(##smaller values for quick run
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 5,
  repeats = 4)

set.seed(1024)

tunegrid=data.frame(C=c(0.25, 0.5, 1,5,8,12,100))
tunegrid

svmfit <- train(Species ~ ., data = training, 
                method = "svmLinear", 
                trControl = fitControl,
                tuneGrid= tunegrid) 

#print this, it will give model's  accuracy (on train data) given various 
# parameter values
svmfit

#C       Accuracy   Kappa
#0.25    0.9533333  0.930
#0.50    0.9666667  0.950
#1.00    0.9766667  0.965
#5.00    0.9800000  0.970
#8.00    0.9833333  0.975
#12.00   0.9833333  0.975
#100.00  0.9400000  0.910 
#The final value used for the model was C = 8.  

# it has already chosen the best model (as per train Accuracy )
# how well does it work on test data?
preds <-predict(svmfit, testing)
cmSVM <-confusionMatrix(preds, testing$Species)
print(cmSVM)
```

Comment: Many thanks!! Good example. Now in my case I just need to verify if value grater than 1 for C are producing best results ,right? Then I will have to keep the part of code that best fits my case! (This because I've tried with value smaller than 1 so far).

Comment: yes. Even though the default value of C is 1 in al the implementations, there is no prescribed range for it.  The only thing we can be sure of is that higher the value of it, tighter the margin ( at the class boundaries)  . That is, it is going to fit the train data better but is more likely to misclassify unseen data. That is  why the model above chooses C=8 instead of 12.

Comment: Could you explain me the difference between the Accuracy displayed by SvmLinear when I type it on console..and the Accuracy of the model on training and testing??

Comment: The accuracy values displayed on typing SvmLinear are the averages of 20 `(number/folds = 5 x repeats=4)` runs for each model . Each model depicts one value of our parameter C.    I will try to expand my answer to show how the whole process  runs. However , if you want to understand how  train and test accuracies differ, Training models without using Caret will give a far better understanding. For example , check the SVM implementation in package e1071 `?e1071::svm`